# Regression function in terms of a set of basis functions

Tags: regression, machine-learning, kernel-smoothing

Regression function in terms of a set of basis functions is given as

$f(x) = \sum_{m=1}^M \beta_m h_m(x) + \beta_0$$

To estimate $\beta$ and $\beta_0$ we minimize the following expression.

$$H(\beta, \beta_0) = \sum_{i=1}^N V(y_i - f(x_i)) + \frac \lambda 2 \sum _{m=1}^M \beta_m^2$$
(The constant is not penalized)

Find $\hat \beta, \hat \beta_0$ and $\hat f$.

---

I know that if $\beta_0$ was penalized than the solution to this problem would be (they sey $\beta_0 = 0$
$$\hat f = \sum_i^N \hat \alpha_i K(x, x_i)$$
where $\alpha = (HH^T + \lambda I)^{-1}y$ and $K(x,y) = \sum_{m=1}^M h_m(x)h_m(y)$

But I do not understand what changes if the constant is not penalized.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the source of the equations above (if there is one)?

Comment: p. 436. 
https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf